# Multiple Parameters or is there any way to force use of setters (Java)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop, setter

I have a java class named Transactions, with several methods. On in particular, inserts in Sqlite database all values representing a new transaction, something like this:

> Date; Time; Category; Payee; Payer; Value; Tags; Description (...)

When I call the method to save a new Transaction, it looks like:

```
new Transactions().saveNewTransaction(String date, String time, String category, Int Payee, Int Payer, String value, String tags, String Description (...)
```

I think this method seems big, bad for readable code and the best way would be those fields be as variables from Transactions class and the method saveNewTransaction(), takes no parameters but instead accessing the variables inside the class.

The only problem is: how can I force to a class (In my case an Activity class) call all setters needed to save a new transaction?

The risk would be call saveNewTransaction() and several fields with values not set by the Activity class (at least the method assures all fields must be set by the caller)

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a class with the property same as the values you want to save and then create a method like saveNewTransaction(object) by passing the instance of newly created class..

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that each created Transactions object should result in some database entry, you could consider dropping the saveNewtTransaction method and instead perform the save-action within some "builder" class:

```
public class TransactionBuilder {
private Date date;

public TransactionsBuilder with(@NonNull Date date){
    this.date = date;
    return this;
}

public Transaction build(){
    validateFields();

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.set(date);

    createADatabaseEntry(transaction);
    return transaction;
}

private void validateFields() {
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(date, "The date cannot be null.");
}
```

Have the [checker framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) issue compiler warnings, when developers try to pass null to setters annotated with @NonNull.

Obviously, in your case, the builder would have some different with()-methods, namely some which matches what is needed for your Transactiion object / saveNewTransaction()-method.

Ps I have not given it any thought what your Transaction class is all about. But if the Transactions class only has that one method, I would create a variant of above mentioned solution:

1. Create an interface with a single method that defines the functionality.
2. Create an implementation which contains the logic of your saveNewTransactions()-method. Only difference being that this method should only accept a single argument, which is an "input bean", fx TransactionInputBean.
3. Create your input bean (a simply class with private fields, and public getters&setters.
4. Create a builder for the input bean.

Answer (score 0):

you could leave all of these variables uninitialized or set them to a value that shouldn't occur by the setters (eg. -1).

Then in your `new Transactions().save();` you'd need to check if they still have that value.

But this solution won't work in the way you wrote above, because you are already saving the transaction when you create the object. And here you'd need to create the new object first and then call all the setters.

Your transactions class could look like this:

```
package de.jeanma.stackOverflow;

import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;

public class Transactions{
    private String date, time, category, value, tags, description;
    private int payee, payer;

    public Transactions(){
    //Add everything here, needed for the constructor
    }
    public Transactions(String date, String time, String category, int payee, //I recommend creating an constructor that sets the values as well, beacause you
        int payer, String value, String tags, String Description){ // might want to create the object and call the save() directly withoud calling every setter one by one          
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.category = category;
        this.value = value;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.description = description;
        this.payee = payee;
        this.payer = payer;
        //Add everything here, needed for the constructor as well
    }

    //Here you can place all your other methods

    public void save(){
        if(!(isInitialized(date) && isInitialized(time) && isInitialized(category) && isInitialized(value) //here all values are checked if they are initialized. 
            && isInitialized(tags) && isInitialized(description) && isInitialized(Integer.valueOf(payee)) //The primitive int's are made to complex Integer's because 
            && isInitialized(Integer.valueOf(payer)))){                                                 // the method isInitialized() expects an object 
        //here you could throw an exception or do something like: System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    private boolean isInitialized(Object Obj){ // this is the method that's checking if the value is initialized
        if(Obj.equals(null)) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    //Add all the setters here (I'm too lazy to do that now)

}
```

I hope that this awnser satisfies you.